# Validar input con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validación, script

Quiero validar que al presionar un botón se valide si el input, en caso de estar vacío que salga un `alert` y que haga foco en ese `input` pero lo que sucede es que si esta vacío me sale el alerta pero me manda a otra página.
Objetivo. que al estar vacío el input salga un `alert` y haga foco en el botón. Sino está vació que se redirija a otra página que se declara en el `action=""`.

**Código modificado**

**Formulario:**

```
<form onsubmit="return control();" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" >
                <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" >
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" required>

                <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
        </form>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    function control() {
        if (document.getElementById('uname') == null
            || document.getElementById('uname') == "") {
            alert("El campo no puede estar vacío.");
            document.getElementById('uname').focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

**El error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser debido a que el formulario se estaría intentado procesar, lo que puedes hacer es obtener al botón de validación y darle un `preventDefault` para que haga la tarea asignada pero permanezcas en la misma página

Comment: Sí, eso me ha funcionado la cosa es que agregando esa línea si agrego un valor al campo, me sale el `alert` del error y me deja en la misma página. @BetaM

Comment: Otra alternativa a las ya comentadas, puede ser `onsubmit` en el form. Si devuelves true en el js hará lo que está en `action`, en el caso contrario no. `onsubmit="return control()"`

Comment: De hecho, hice eso también pero el resultado fue el mismo @JuanJosé

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo te dejé como respuesta un par de opciones, chécalas y me avisas como te va

Comment: Las estuve probando pero como te dije, si está vacía no sucede nada lo cual es lo que quiero pero si el campo tiene valores tampoco hace nada @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si lo que buscas es a algo como esto, pero con Jquery seria algo asi:

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#searchForm').on('submit', function(event) {
            var $searchValue = $('#searchValue').val();
            if ($searchValue === "") {
               event.preventDefault();
                  var error = '<br><span style="color: red;">Error. Vacio.</span>';
                  $('#searchValue').after($(error).fadeOut(2000));
                  $('#searchValue').css( "border-color","red");
            }
         });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="processadordeforma.php" method="POST" id="searchForm">
   <p>Search <input type="text" id="searchValue"></p>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Nota que si el valor del input esta vacio. La forma no se postea, y se adjunta un `<span>` con error en rojo en la parte de abajo que desaparece despues de un tiempo. Puedes hacer esto para todos tus inputs y ademas agregar mas cosas de validacion que te den diferentes mensajes de error. Nota tambien que si el input si tiene un valor la forma se postea.

Comment: Vaya, esto ha sido de otra forma pero es la respuesta que necesitaba, muchas gracias

Comment: Al jQuery, ¿Lo puedo meter en una carpeta o sí o sí lo debo tener en el html donde se encuentra el form?

Comment: De alguna manera debes de ligar el jquery, ya sea que lo tengas en una carpeta o como liga a un cdn. Yo lo uso como cdn en mi `header` `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>` pero pues es cuestion de preferencia.

Answer (score 1):

Opciones:

- La forma mas simple sería el agregar el atributo `required` a tus `inputs` eso generaría que cuando presiones el botón del formulario si es que estos no se han llenado entonces te quedes en la misma página y el foco se ponga en dicho input

  ```
  <input type="text" required>
  ```

Por otro lado, si lo dejamos con JS, te manda a otra página por que:

- Tienes un atributo `action` declarado en el `form` diciéndole a donde mandar la información
- No estás previniendo el comportamiento de `submit` que el botón tendría se lleve a cabo

Como ejemplo para que veas como implementarlo pudieras hacerlo así:

- Obtenemos y asignamos en variables tanto a la caja de texto como al botón
- Al botón le agregamos un listener en su evento `click`
- Por dentro del callback prevenimos el comportamiento por defecto
- En un condicional evaluamos si la propiedad `value` del `input` esta vacía

  - En caso de estar vacía le indicamos que el `input` tenga el foco activado

```html
    <form action="url">
      <input id="elemento" type="text">
      <input id="envio" type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        let botonEnvio = document.getElementById('envio');
        let texto      = document.getElementById('elemento');
      
        botonEnvio.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          
          if (texto.value === '') {
            texto.focus();
          }
        })
    </script>
```

**EDICIÓN**

Para complementar mi respuesta considero que debería ser así:

- Sigues los pasos anteriores
- En el `else` harías una petición AJAX mandando a tu backend los datos
- Una vez recibidos en el backend harías la consulta SQL necesaria para verificar la existencia del registro
- Una vez lo verifiques si existe el registro entonces haces un redirect tal vez al panel donde corresponde y sino haces un redirect al mismo formulario de login

Comment: Gracias, pero el problema es reincidente. Es decir, lo que me muestras funciona  al perfecto al momento de presionar el botón cuando está vacío el campo pero cuando el campo no está vacío no sucede nada

Comment: y que quieres que ocurra cuando el campo esté lleno? que se procese tu formulario? @FranqoBalsamo, te lo pregunto por que eso no esta explicado en tu pregunta

Comment: Que me redirija a otra página. Lo que quiero es que si está vacío el campo, haga foco en en campo y no suceda nada en la página. Sino está vacío quiero que vaya a otra página, por eso el form tiene el action

Comment: Vaya, mas tarde regreso a editar y proponer

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

En tu código he encontrado par de errores que son interesantes de corregir.

En primer lugar cuando haces `document.getElementById(uname)` se te ha olvidado poner entre comillas el ID, ya que no lo está detectando como texto, si no como objeto.

Para solucionar que el formulario no haga el `action` si no cumple los requisitos, es necesario que utilices `onsubmit`.

```js
function control() {

    if (document.getElementById('uname') == null || document.getElementById('uname')=="") {
        alert("El campo no puede estar vacío.");
        document.getElementById('uname').focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form class="modal-content animate" onsubmit="return control();" method="post" action="index.html" >
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                <img src="~/Images/00.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Usuario:</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" >

                <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña:</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw">

                <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Recuérdame
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Al devolver `false` en el javascript, no se ejecutará el `action`. Si devuelves `true` lo ejecutará.

Otro error es la forma en la que das focus al input. Estabas usando una forma incorrecta. Para hacer focus debes hacer: `document.getElementById('uname').focus();`, ya que necesitas hacer referencia al input del HTML.

PD: teniendo en cuenta el potencial que tiene onsubmit, podrías aprovecharlo para aplicar más restricciones incluso al campo de contraseña. (O regex si el usuario debe ser un email, etc...)

Puedes echarle un vistazo a la documentación del [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la idea pero tampoco ha funcionado

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que exactamente no ha funcionado? En principio comprueba si el campo usuario está vacío, y en ese caso no hace el action.

Comment: Pues, mira he subido un `gif` mostrando como esto no hace nada. 
He modificado mi código de la fomar en la que lo explicas pero como se ve en el `gif` borro el campo y al presionar el botón o enter me redirige a la página cosa que no tendría que hacer sin mencionar que el `alert` no sale

Comment: He modificado el código de la pregunta para que no sea tan largo de leer. Es decir, quité los componentes que no interesan como `div`, etc